# Kalman Filter in R with flow/stock variables

Tags: r, kalman-filter, state-space-models

I have a model defined in state-space form as:

$y_t=F_t α_t+Γ_t w_t+ε_t$

$α_t=Gα_{t-1}+Rη_t$

$ε_t∼(0,H_t )  ,η_t∼(0,Q)$ - measurements of  vector and transition shocks

Where y_t is a multivariate vector of length m = 4, and α_t is p=1 dimensional (I think). Furthermore, m contains 2 stock variables and 2 flow variables

My questions are:

1. I know in the R DLM package you can easily handle missing observations via the input JFF, JGG, etc. I'm wondering if there are any further modifications I need to make to take into account the fact that say one variable is daily and another variable monthly, and there are a non-constant number of days in the month. More specifically, do the dimensions of the measurement and transition matrices change from m by p, and p by p, to something different, to take into account the non constant number of days in a month? [This](https://edoc.ub.uni-muenchen.de/9681/1/wohlrabe_klaus.pdf) paper treats it, but it is specfically in the context of Arma models and there is no code example.
2. Similarly, given the fact that 2 of my observation matrices are flow variables, what changes do I need to make to my measurement and transition matrices (as well H and Q), to take into account that they are flow variables? [This](https://edoc.ub.uni-muenchen.de/9681/1/wohlrabe_klaus.pdf) paper treats what changes need to be made for flow variables, but I haven't seen anything else that confirms it.

Comment: what's $H$? Do you mean $T_t$?

Comment: Edited model specification to include details of shock elements @Taylor

Comment: Regarding your first question, this would be covered in the documentation. I remember having had to answer this question myself when I was using the DLM package. RATS I'm not really familiar with though. You might have a hard time getting an answer because giving one requires reading the paper (that you haven't provided), and it involves reading the documentation for code.